# how to use tar '--remove-files' option inside find -exec?

Tags: unix, find, tar

I've got a number of very large log files which I want to compress **individually** so I can't use xargs or pipe stdout to get a huge compressed file.

I'm trying to do this:

```
find . -mtime +1 -iname "*.log" -exec tar -jcvf {} --remove-files \;
```

But I get:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

I've tried escaping the double dash (--), which I believe is the problem, to no avail.

And yes, find does actually find a file:

```
find . -mtime +1 -iname "*.log" 
./20141002.tcp.log                  # just a test file...
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tar` is complaining because you miss to pass an argument to its `-f` option, not because of the `--` which you were suspecting.

Here is one way to fix your command that works with `GNU tar` which is likely what you are using:

```
find . -mtime +1 -iname "*.log" -exec tar --remove-files -jcvf {}.tar.bz2 {} \;
```

In case your `find` implementation wants `{}` to stay alone, like the POSIX standard specifies, you might run:

```
find . -mtime +1 -iname "*.log" -exec sh -c 'tar --remove-files -jcvf $1.tar.bz2 $1' sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question just for the sake of completeness.

As I could not delete the source files as they were being compressed, I just made a wee script to scrap them manually. 
Not fancy, but living in cron, works wonders: my vol occupancy went from 60% to 10%.

here the script

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/log/remote -mtime +1 -iname "*.log" > /tmp/tmp_file
for i in $(cat /tmp/tmp_file) ; do tar jcvf $i.bz2 $i && rm -rf $i ; done 
rm -rf /tmp/tmp_file
```